# how to draw a smooth bell curve using google graph?

Tags: php, google-visualization, codeigniter-2

Let me try my best to explain the question framed here:

I'm trying to draw normally-distributed graphs (aka bell-curve) in a Codeigniter application. For charting applications, I'm using Google Graph.

Now, let me describe what I'm doing in order to get X-Y axis value(s) and to generate the chart:

i) arranging the values fetched from the concerned db table in ascending order (treating them as X-values)

ii) calculating Y-values based on those X-values...here, I'm using the following mysql function to generate those Y-values:

```
    BEGIN
        DECLARE x FLOAT;
        DECLARE z FLOAT;
        DECLARE t FLOAT;
        DECLARE ans FLOAT;
        DECLARE returnvalue DECIMAL(10,5);
        SET z = (val-mean)/sigma;
        IF val < z THEN SET x= 0.5-z;
        ELSEIF  val = z THEN    SET x = 0.5;
        ELSE SET x= 0.5+z;
        END IF;
        SET returnvalue = (1/(sigma * SQRT( 2.0 * 3.14159265358979 ))) * EXP(-((val-mean)*(val-mean)) / (2*(sigma*sigma)));
        RETURN returnvalue;
    END
```

Input Parameters are: val FLOAT, mean FLOAT, sigma FLOAT

Where, **mean** = SELECT FORMAT(avg(a.`val`),2) as avg_value FROM `tableX` a,

and **sigma** = SELECT FORMAT(stddev(b.`val`),2) AS std_value FROM `tableX` b

iii)  finally, while I'm plotting these value(s) using google-graph areaChart it's not generating a smooth one which is the requirement in this case.

Following are the graph(s) we're dealing with: graph#1 is my requirement and graph#2 is what I'm getting, while plotting those points in Google-Graph.

[Graph 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU9Oh.png)

[Graph 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZTFrS.png)

So, Please let me know where I'm going wrong...is it the mysql function where I'm generating normally-distributed values or in the graph-plotting?